# BigQuery vs Elasticsearch for analysing and storing application logs

Tags: elasticsearch, google-bigquery, kibana

I'm investigating the merits of using BigQuery for gaining insights into application logfiles. The logs are produced by Java and C# applications, most of them on cloud-based VMs. I'm interested to hear whether others have done this and of the relative merits of BigQuery vs ElasticSearch/Logstash/Kibana.

The advantage of BigQuery seems to be that it can deal with huge amounts of data whereas the ELK solutions seems maybe better suited to the non-structured nature of logfiles, especially when they come from different systems.

I'd also like to display information on a dashboard. Kibana seems to be very good for that. How easy is it to create dashboards using the Google solution (using google sheets, etc)?

Thoughts, use-cases?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

2017 update: Elastic officially supported on GCP

- https://www.elastic.co/blog/announcing-the-ga-of-elastic-cloud-hosted-elasticsearch-on-google-cloud-platform-gcp

---

Elasticsearch and BigQuery work great together. BigQuery will take as much data as you have and query it in any way you want in seconds. Meanwhile a well tuned Elasticsearch installation will give you answers in less than a second, but only for certain queries over a limited amount of data.

See this post by Ory at Rounds, where they detail how they use both:

https://medium.com/@oryband/collecting-user-data-and-usage-ffa84c4dba34

The two top titles that summarize their reasons to do both:

- Live Data with Elasticsearch
- Big Data with Google BigQuery

Comment: http://www.rounds.com/blog/collecting-user-data-and-usage/  since https is not openning

Comment: But how you save logs to elastic search? do you use logstash?

Comment: @KassemShehady I use filebeat to ship the logs from the clients, and logstash on the servers to process them before sending them off to elasticsearch

Comment: I finally uses apache beam ElasticSearchIO https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/java/io/elasticsearch/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/elasticsearch/ElasticsearchIO.java

Comment: new link for the article: http://rounds.com/www.rounds.com/blog/collecting-user-data-and-usage/index.html

Comment: a functioning link to that article >< https://medium.com/@oryband/collecting-user-data-and-usage-ffa84c4dba34